# Call Activity from FragmentTabHosts

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

Currently I have the following code:-

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Fragment B"),FragmentB.class, null);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Fragment C"),FragmentC.class, null);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator("Fragment D"),FragmentD.class, null);
```

Here I am calling fragment classes B,C,D from my TabHosts. Is it possible that instead of calling another fragment class I call an activity. I want to start an activity once the tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording, format and question itself is very badly formatted.

Anyway, if you want to start an activity set a tab change listener and fire an intent to start an activity when you get a callback:

```
yourTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(…);
```

source: [TabHost Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setOnTabChangedListener(android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener))